# Strange error with Lotus Domino SNMP agent

Tags: snmp, ibm-domino

On most of the 40+ Domino servers at my disposal, enabling SNMP is simply a matter of running:

```
net stop snmp
[domino path]\lnsnmp -Sc
net start snmp
net start lnsnmp
```

Followed by:

```
load quryset
```

...in the Domino console. Now I've come across a server that throws this error after `load quryset`:

```
load quryset
08/03/2011 09:17:09 AM  QuerySet Handler started
08/03/2011 09:17:10 AM  Lotus Domino QuerySet Handler (Version 8.0)
08/03/2011 09:17:10 AM  Failed to open event: LNIPC_SERVSEM[2].
08/03/2011 09:17:10 AM  System Error: 1998597488.
08/03/2011 09:17:10 AM  Lotus Domino SNMP Agent is not available.
```

Has anybody seen anything like this before? Any suggested workarounds?

**Edit**
If I shut down the lnsnmp service, I don't get the `LNIPC_SERVSEM` and `System Error:` lines.

This message repeats in the Lotus Domino snmp agent window:

```
hConEvt - failed to recieve ack from client
```

Comment: I'd assume the "net start lnsnmp" is failing.  Is the lnsnmp process actually running?

Comment: "net start lnsnmp" does not show any errors, and the service is started. But that's good input, I'll try and see what happens if I try to load quryset without it running.

Comment: Only other thing I'd suggest then is checking the Windows Event log to see if the lnsnmp and or snmp daemons are running or erroring.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to wake up a year old thread, but posting a possible solution maybe useful for others.

I was having the same issue, and I solved it. I was running the Domino in application mode, when I configured it to run as a SERVICE, the

```
Lotus Domino SNMP Agent is not available.
```

error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Has the Domino MIB been registered with the SNMP subsystem?  Look in:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMP\Parameters\ExtensionAgents
```

You should see several default extensions, like hostmib, and RFCxxxx (like 8 or 9 of them) 
and one for either Lotus or Domino.  If they are missing, you'll need to check docs for next actions - like reinstalling or maybe manually creating entries in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Issue relates to SPR MSHN8L8JPX and should be fixed in the latest version of 8.5.1 onwards.

Comment: question showed up on my activity log. No idea why, thought I'd answer it despite being over a year late.